# Split each ul with 4 li elements

Tags: jquery

Need quick help to split the each ul with 4 li elements using jquery.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 1</li>
        <li>Ele 2</li>
        <li>Ele 3</li>
        <li>Ele 4</li>
        <li>Ele 5</li>
        <li>Ele 6</li>
        <li>Ele 7</li>
        <li>Ele 8</li>
        <li>Ele 9</li>
        <li>Ele 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Restriction is.. have to split each "ul" element to have 4 "li" inside for content slider. Jquery script have to align like below HTML structure.

```
<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 1</li>
        <li>Ele 2</li>
        <li>Ele 3</li>
        <li>Ele 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 5</li>
        <li>Ele 6</li>
        <li>Ele 7</li>
        <li>Ele 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 9</li>
        <li>Ele 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to do some research, show what you have tried, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues.
See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `li` elements, and wrap them in a new container like

```js
var $scs = $('.slide-content');
$scs.each(function() {
  var $sc = $(this),
    $lis = $sc.find('li'),
    $lst = $sc;
  for (var i = 4; i < $lis.length; i += 4) {
    $lst = $lis.slice(i, i + 4).wrapAll('<div class="slide-content"><ul class="container"></ul></div>').closest('div').insertAfter($lst)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-content">
  <ul class="container">
    <li>Ele 1</li>
    <li>Ele 2</li>
    <li>Ele 3</li>
    <li>Ele 4</li>
    <li>Ele 5</li>
    <li>Ele 6</li>
    <li>Ele 7</li>
    <li>Ele 8</li>
    <li>Ele 9</li>
    <li>Ele 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="slide-content">
  <ul class="container">
    <li>Ele 1</li>
    <li>Ele 2</li>
    <li>Ele 3</li>
    <li>Ele 4</li>
    <li>Ele 5</li>
    <li>Ele 6</li>
    <li>Ele 7</li>
    <li>Ele 8</li>
    <li>Ele 9</li>
    <li>Ele 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="slide-content">
  <ul class="container">
    <li>Ele 1</li>
    <li>Ele 2</li>
    <li>Ele 3</li>
    <li>Ele 4</li>
    <li>Ele 5</li>
    <li>Ele 6</li>
    <li>Ele 7</li>
    <li>Ele 8</li>
    <li>Ele 9</li>
    <li>Ele 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr />
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your quick reply.. sorry.. i forgot to mention.. i had multiple "slide-content" inside the page like "<div class="slide-content item1">", "<div class="slide-content item2">, <div class="slide-content item3">, <div class="slide-content item4">. Now it merge out all <li> elements into single "<div class="slide-content">".. is it possible to seperate? Thanks

Comment: Hi Arun.. 1 last thing.. i want to hide "<span class="icon-arrowleft">" or "<span class="icon-arrowright">", if <li> less than 4 within <ul>... i tried to hide..but it removes icon completely.. Thanks

Comment: Added Arun.. Thanks for your great help!!

Comment: @TDG whether each slider has the arrow element - is it like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/961hroz6/2/

Comment: Hi Arun.. yes.. your code is rite.. each <ul> will have pagination bullet with right & left arrow.. pagination area will be @ bottom of the <div> container..

Comment: Oh no.. Sorry my mistake.. Pagination will come after <slide-content>. Very sorry bro..

Comment: @TDG sorry... unless you can share a update fiddle with correct markup... I won't able to offer much help

Comment: Updated your Code snippet boss.. Sorry.. <pagination> container will be after "slide-content" div element.

Comment: @TDG sorry... not able to use that.. edit the fiddle attached above and share the update link

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.append()` `:lt()` selector , `do... while` loop to append elements from within `.slide-content` to new jQuery object , while last `.container` element `li` elements `.length` is `4`

```js
do {

  $("body").append($("<div></div>", {
    "class": "slide-content",
    "html": $("<ul>", {
      "class": "container"
    }).append($(".container:first li:lt(4)"))
  }));

} while ($(".container:eq(-1) li").length === 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-content">
  <ul class="container">
    <li>Ele 1</li>
    <li>Ele 2</li>
    <li>Ele 3</li>
    <li>Ele 4</li>
    <li>Ele 5</li>
    <li>Ele 6</li>
    <li>Ele 7</li>
    <li>Ele 8</li>
    <li>Ele 9</li>
    <li>Ele 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A hard-coded answer would look like so:

```js
$(function() {
    //grab the original div element
    var orig = $('div.slide-content');
    
    //manipulate it
    orig
    //insert after it, a clone div-ul with last two li's
    .after( orig.clone().find('ul').html( orig.find('li:gt(7)') ).end() )
    //but you really want li's 5 - 8 to come after the original
    .after( orig.clone().find('ul').html( orig.find('li:gt(3)') ).end() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 1</li>
        <li>Ele 2</li>
        <li>Ele 3</li>
        <li>Ele 4</li>
        <li>Ele 5</li>
        <li>Ele 6</li>
        <li>Ele 7</li>
        <li>Ele 8</li>
        <li>Ele 9</li>
        <li>Ele 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**BUT**, if the number of `li` elements is not fixed, **AND**, if there're many groups of `li` elements that need to be rearranged:

```js
$(function() {
    //grab the original div elements
    var origALL = $('div.slide-content');
    origALL.each(function() {
        //grab current original div element
        var orig = $(this);
        //find number of li elements in current div element
        var nli  = orig.find('li').length;
        //find largest multiple of 4 less than nli and subtract 1
        var lm4  = Math.floor( nli / 4 ) * 4 - 1;
        //iterate and append appropriate li elements
        for(var i=lm4; i > 0; i = i - 4) {
            orig.after( orig.clone().find('ul').html( orig.find('li:gt(' + i + ')') ).end() );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 1</li>
        <li>Ele 2</li>
        <li>Ele 3</li>
        <li>Ele 4</li>
        <li>Ele 5</li>
        <li>Ele 6</li>
        <li>Ele 7</li>
        <li>Ele 8</li>
        <li>Ele 9</li>
        <li>Ele 10</li>
        <li>Ele 11</li>
        <li>Ele 12</li>
        <li>Ele 13</li>
        <li>Ele 14</li>
        <li>Ele 15</li>
        <li>Ele 16</li>
        <li>Ele 17</li>
    </ul>
</div>
----------
<div class="slide-content">
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ele 1</li>
        <li>Ele 2</li>
        <li>Ele 3</li>
        <li>Ele 4</li>
        <li>Ele 5</li>
        <li>Ele 6</li>
        <li>Ele 7</li>
        <li>Ele 8</li>
        <li>Ele 9</li>
        <li>Ele 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```